# How to use GET method to generate random dice number using object oriented php?

Tags: php

The problem when I write get and rand, I do not get it right

tried yt and many websites and still don't do it

```
public function roll() {


}
```

Comment: Please, correct the question because we can't understand anything what you are asking

Comment: How to generate random numbers when I refresh the website without a button

Comment: `echo(rand(10,100));` "I do not get it right" << what you mean ?

Comment: MorganFreeFarm using php classes

Comment: what do you mean with _how to use get method to generate randome number_?

Comment: Using php classes how to random generate a number, sorry if my explanation is bizarre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, but:

```
<?php

class Number{
    public function getRandNumber($min, $max) {
        echo(rand($min,$max));
    }
}

$number = new Number();
$number->getRandNumber(0, 100);


?>
```

[rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Comment: And if you refresh the website, I want the website to show numbers between 0 and 100 just like you wrote

Comment: Then on page you refresh call the class, like this `$number = new Number();

$number->getRandNumber(0, 100);`